# Is it possible to develop chrome extensions with web3.js or Ethers.js?

Tags: node.js, ethereum, web3js, ethers.js

I want to develop an ethereum wallet chrome extension.

While developing a simple prototype, I noticed that the node.js module cannot be run directly from the chrome extension.

But I must use web3.js or ethers.js.

Is there any way to develop Chrome extensions using web3.js or ethers.js?

Comment: Unfortunately parts of web3.js is written in C++ and is compiled into binary code (x86, ARM etc depending on your machine) and this means it cannot be used in browsers unless you rewrite it to be NaCl complient but NaCl has been removed from modern Chrome so you can only use older versions of Chrome. Instead of web3 you should look at Metamask instead - the code is open source just like web3.js

Comment: https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension

Comment: @slebetman thank you for your answer :) In Metamask's package.json, both web3 and ethers exist. Does Metamask build a Node.js server and communicate with the frontend using socket.io? I want to make a wallet extension similar to it.

Comment: web3.js and ethers.js can run on client-side without any node.js modules, so your assumption is simply incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

Of course, when we check [the packages of the MetaMask](https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/blob/d929ccdfa86104445b25926b941a9f7793b18b0a/package.json#L203) we will see both `web3` & `ethjs` libraries which is also an extension:

```json
// ...
    "web3": "^..."
// ...
    "ethjs": "^...",
    "ethjs-contract": "^...",
    "ethjs-ens": "^...",
    "ethjs-query": "^...",
// ...
```

What we might do either we can compile it via a tool like `browserify` or import the minified browser version like this(I tested it is working with `metamask-extension-provider` package*):

```
import Web3 from 'web3/dist/web3.min.js';

// or

const Web3 = require('web3/dist/web3.min.js');
```

*A specific version of provider for extensions, check its [docs](https://docs.metamask.io/guide/metamask-extension-provider.html#installation).